# How to access resource with dynamic name in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

If I get the image name as a variable like following:

```
var imageName = SERVICE.getImg();
```

Then, how can I get the resource with `R.drawable.????`, I tried `R.drawable[imageName]`, but it failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont use the NDK hence comment: getResources().getIdentifier (imageName, null , null);  API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, type, package);
```

[This will get you the ID of the resource you are looking for.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  With it, you can then access the resource from the R class.

**Using only the `name` parameter:**

You can also include all the 3 info in the "name" parameter using the following format: `"package:type/image_name"`, something like:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.my.app:drawable/my_image", null, null);
```

This is useful when you're working with external components or libraries that you can't, or don't want to, change how `getIdentifier()` is called. e.g.: [AOSP Launcher3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/o-preview/src/com/android/launcher3/Utilities.java#176)

Comment: @nicholas, I got resource not found exception. If I have a image named "icon1.gif" in folder "drawable", isn't it getIdentifier("icon1", "gif", "drawable") ??

Comment: Did you look at the link?  I think it would be ("icon1", "drawable", "the.containing.package")

Comment: @nicholas, what does the.containing.package mean??? Isn't the containing package = "projectName/res/drawable"  ??

Comment: @Leem: the package is your projects package.

Comment: make sure to leave the extension (.png or .jpg) out of the `imageName` String, else `resourceId` will be set to `0x0` integer which refers to **No such resources found**

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: As for `R.id.???` equivalent, it will be `int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "id", getPackageName());`

Comment: It comes at a cost though, if you ever try to `Refactor -> Remove un-used resources`, it will delete the resource you dynamically access. So unless it's absolutely necessary, better not do it.

Comment: Can confirm this works for me, although my code was ```int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layoutName, "layout", context.getPackageName());```

Comment: perfect answer.. Thank you !

Answer (score 15):

You need reflection.

Suppose you have R.drawable.image1, if you wanna access it via the String name "image1", following should work:

```
String Name = "image1";
int id = R.drawable.class.getField(Name).getInt(null);
```

But notice it only get the Id of the image, you still need the inflater to get the actual drawable from it.

Comment: Why does this work when the other `getIdentifier()` methods fail?

Comment: Fine but didn't work, when minifyEnabled = true .

Answer (score 3):

Use this function

```
public static String getResourceString(String name, Context context) {
    int nameResourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
            "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (nameResourceID == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No resource string found with name " + name);
    } else {
        return context.getString(nameResourceID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method which will give you the resource id by its name. Check [this](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html) thread for more details.

Comment: what is parameter "defPackage" in getIdentifier()??? Isn't it "projectName/res/drawable"  ??

Comment: defPackage - Optional default package to find, if "package:" is not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit package. Your name should look something like this org.anddev.android.testproject:drawable/bug where bug is the drawable name and org.anddev.android.testproject is your main package name. Please read the article !!

Comment: Second link in answer is outdated.