# How do I randomly pass a variable to R.drawable in Eclipse for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to get a random image from my drawable folder, and set it in an ImageView. All the images start with "kitten" and are followed by a number, 1 through 17, which is hardcoded into the variable "kittensMax". When I run my code, it throws a NumberFormatException on the third line here. I believe the problem is that "R.drawable.kitten#" is not a number that can be "parsed" to an int, since it represents an int. Any suggestions?

```
Random r = new Random();
String drawableKitten = "R.drawable.kitten" + r.nextInt(kittensMax);
kittensImageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(drawableKitten));
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583843/how-to-access-resource-with-dynamic-name-in-my-case) should be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("kitten" + r.nextInt(kittensMax), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

This uses a method in the Resources class which allows you to find the ID for resources using their name, type and package name. You can see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

It works similarly for other types or resource like `id`, `string`, `raw` etc. Just change the second parameter to reflect the type of resource you want.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Can you explain your code so I can understand it?