# Android/Java - Pass Variables as Parameter to Methods

Tags: java, android, methods, parameter-passing

I find myself repeating the same lines of code, and I'd like to automate this a bit.

I'm doing the following to change the color of text in a view to correspond with correct/incorrect answers:

`((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.quiz_answer_2e)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EE7674"));`

I'd like to pass in parameters so I don't have to repeat this, I would prefer to call the function and set parameters to the function like:

```
public void setCorrect(String viewType, String viewName, String thisColor) {
    if (thisColor.equals("red")) {
        thisColor = "#EE7674";
    } else {
        thisColor = "#9DBF9E";
    }
    ((**viewType**) findViewById(R.id.**viewName**)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor(**thisColor**));
}
```

Where **viewType**, **viewName** and **thisColor** are passed to the method. Is there a way to do this?

I tried saving the value to a String, but couldn't determine how to get that string to run from the method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your method based on the following:

1. `setTextColor(int color)` is defined in `TextView` and is inherited by the applicable classes such as `EditText`, `CheckBox`, `Button`, etc.
2. Whilst you can get a resource by its identifier (e.g. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583843/how-to-access-resource-with-dynamic-name-in-my-case)) you're more likely to encounter run time errors this way. So instead I'd recommend passing the resource ID as an `int`
3. At the moment you have a correct / incorrect (binary) color decision, so make the parameter a `boolean` with a self explanatory name such as `correct` and use the information to identify the color resource.

This would lead to a solution such as:

```
public void setCorrect(int viewId, boolean correct) {
    int colorId = correct ? R.color.correct : R.color.incorrect;
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), colorId);
    ((TextView) findViewById(viewId)).setTextColor(color);
}
```

Where the `colors.xml` in `res/values` would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="correct">#9DBF9E</color>
    <color name="incorrect">#EE7674</color>
</resources>
```