# How to access drawable from variable to set icon to an alert dialog

Tags: android, variables, android-alertdialog

I would like to change my Alert Dialog icon from a variable. Actualy I do :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( this); 
alert.setTitle("Level"+(OEDPrefs.level_number()));
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

but "icon" is always the same. I would like it to change according to the level number. 
I would like to do something like :

```
num = OEDPrefs.level_number();
icon_var = "icon"+num;

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( this); 
alert.setTitle("Level"+(OEDPrefs.level_number()));
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_var);
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access resource with dynamic name in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583843/how-to-access-resource-with-dynamic-name-in-my-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
num = OEDPrefs.level_number();
icon_var = "icon"+num;

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(icon_var , "drawable", context.getPackageName());

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( this); 
alert.setTitle("Level"+(OEDPrefs.level_number()));
alert.setIcon(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of icons for different levels. Turning to a specific element of the array you will receive the id of the icon for a certain level

```
int[] icons = {R.drawable.icon1,R.drawable.icon2 ... };
```

get an icon for i level

```
int icon = icons[i];
```